# I'm having a problem saving a file that saves the last line python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

```
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('1.txt','r')]
for names in lines:
   for x in range(100):
        y=names.lower()+f'{x:02}'
        print(y)
        with open('1.txt','w') as f:
        f.write(y + '\n')
```

This code reads a file and adds 00 to 99
I have a problem saving data to the same file and replacing old data with new data
It saves the last line
I want a solution, thanks

Comment: The `'a'` in your `open` call stands for "append". Use `'w'` for "write" if you don't want that behavior

Comment: I meant w, but I misspelled code here
but the same problem

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want every name that is on a separate line to be re-written in the new file 100 times adding digits 00-99 at the back. Say no more...

```py
def rewrite_names_v1():
    
    #get list of names
    with open('demo.txt','r') as file:
        names = [line.strip('\n') for line in file]

    with open('demo.txt','w') as file:
        for name in names:
            lowercase_name = name.lower()
            for x in range(100):
                result = lowercase_name+f'{x:02}'
                # print(result)
                if name != names[-1] or x != 99:
                    file.write(result+'\n')
                else:
                    file.write(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rewrite_names_v1() #rewrites file with range(100) as nested loop
```

Comment: yes thanks you this is what I want